# How to keep Windows Server 2012's desktop always on

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

Now I want to write a program to broadcast my desktop video. It works well at first. But when I upload it to my server, open it, close the RDP connection, I found that the output of the program is all black. When I close the RDP connection, the desktop will not be always on so the program cannot catch anything so the output is all black.

So can I do something to let the desktop always on after I close the RDP connection?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, you're picking the wrong tools for the job. A server should, most of the time, have no users logged in and no desktops shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your answer or not, but maybe you have to try the "disconnect" button instead of the "log out" button when you decide to close your remote desktop connection with server

Comment: I use "disconnect" button instead of "log out". But when I disconnected from the server, the whole desktop session seems to be closed, or maybe paused. When I log in again, the desktop session wakes up and work again.

Comment: @iOrange have you found any solution for it, I am also facing the same problem in Window Server 2022